# What are my options for changing default texts in SharePoint?

Tags: language, language-pack

What are my options for changing default texts in SharePoint? We have a language pack (dutch) installed but some translations seem to be a little bit off or weird.

Is there a way to update/replace those texts?

I could, obviously, edit the resources files in the 14/15-hive but doing so is a big no-no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the resources files is your only option unless you want to replace them with your own.

Yes, some may consider it a big no-no. But there isn't much other option.

Just make sure to keep backups of the resources files you do modify, in case the files gets overwritten by an update from Microsoft.